# How to change the theme of all apps?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, kde, theme

When I installed Debian I installed alternative desktop environments such as KDE aside GNOME. When I ran a KDE program instead of its GNOME counterpart by mistake, the theme of all applications changed. To revert the unwanted modification, I installed `gnome-tweak-tool` and went to `Appearance > Themes > Applications` to reset the theme. While most applications immediately respected the change, some applications that were downloaded directly from my browser and not `apt` did not. Only after a reboot did their themes also return to normal.

Is there a command that forcibly changes themes for all apps regardless of how they were installed? Also how can I prevent changes to themes when running apps for desktop environments other than my default?